# How to delete a single resource in Azure using the dotnet SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have been trying to use DeleteById, but from all the examples I have seen, it seems like you need to know what type of resource you are deleting to use this method.

This is how I have been attempting to call it, but I get the error 'IResourcesOperations' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteById' and the best extension method overload 'PolicyAssignmentsOperationsExtensions.DeleteById(IPolicyAssignmentsOperations, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IPolicyAssignmentsOperations.'

```
var resourceManagementClient = new 
ResourceManagementClient(TokenCredentials){
        SubscriptionId = AzureSubscriptionId
};

resourceManagementClient.Resources.DeleteById("idhere");
```

I've been getting the same error when trying to use the Delete method.

Is there a way to delete a single resource without knowing what type the resource is? For example, can you delete a resource by knowing the id and the resource group or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can you delete a resource by knowing the id and the resource group or something similar?

Yes, we could delete the single resource with known Id.

Please have a try to use the following code.

```
resourceManagementClient.Resources.DeleteById("resourceId", "Apiversion");
```

Take WebApp for instance- resourceId format:

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}
```

Api vesrion: `2018-02-01`

We could get the Api version from [delete resource API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/deletebyid)

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/{resourceId}?api-version=2018-02-01
```

Packages.config

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" version="1.9.0-preview" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.11" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.12" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I attempted calling the method like this

resourceManagementClient.Resources.DeleteById("/subscriptions/26fa58e3-10f1-407e-bf31-21001f52f95d/resourceGroups/testing1/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/rwerwerwr493", "2018-02-01");

but I got a new error that says: No overload for method 'DeleteById' takes 2 arguments

Comment: How are you getting the api version from a delete call? Are you just parsing the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your resource name should include fully qualified ID of the resource, including the resource name and resource type. Use following format, /subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/{resource-provider-namespace}/{resource-type}/{resource-name}

Refer following - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.resourcesoperationsextensions.deletebyid?view=azure-dotnet